# Django Error: solution_building.ID_CUSTOMER_id may not be NULL

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Can someone help me with this. I am pretty new to this and I kinda a bit blank now. I know maybe its just a silly question but honestly I am stuck.

I get this error:

> Exception Type: IntegrityError at /building/
>
> Exception Value: solution_building.ID_CUSTOMER_id may not be NULL

What am I doing wrong here

views.py

```
class buildingView(UpdateView):
template_name="building.html"
model = building
form_class = buildingForm

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(buildingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  

    context['pk'] = 1
    context['numberOfObjects'] = building.objects.all().count()
   
    return context

def get_object(self, queryset = None):
    try: 
        obj = building.objects.get(id = 1)
    except: 
        obj = building.objects.create(id = 1)
    return obj

def form_valid(self, form):
    
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("building_view", kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']}))
```

and when i doing python manage.py sql i got this

```
CREATE TABLE "solution_building" (
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"ID_CUSTOMER_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "solution_customer" ("id"),
"BUILDING_USE" varchar(2) NOT NULL,
"BUILDING_FLOORSPACE" integer,
```

Needed help. Thank you so much.

model.py

```
class building(models.Model):
id                   = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
ID_CUSTOMER          = models.ForeignKey(customer)
BUILDING_USE         = models.CharField(max_length = 2, blank = True, choices = c.Anvendelse)
BUILDING_FLOORSPACE  = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.ID_CUSTOMER)
```

Comment: can you show your model? Exception Value: solution_building.ID_CUSTOMER_id may not be NULL
means that you are entering a null value for something that shouldn't be null. In this case, it seems that you are referencing a foreign key but you are not inserting the value for the foreign key value "ID_CUSTOMER_id"

Comment: Thks @RyanLiao Yes i posted the models.py. How do i make it so that it will accept also null??

Comment: you ID_Customer must be also null=True and blank=True

Comment: but then it give me an error 'ForeignKey' object is not callable

Answer (score 4):

The error is from here:

```
def get_object(self, queryset = None):
    try: 
        obj = building.objects.get(id = 1)
    except: 
        obj = building.objects.create(id = 1) <---- here
    return obj
```

Your trying to create new building data with the id?

Based on your building table, ID_CUSTOMER, BUILDING_USE, and BUILDING_FLOORSPACE required value. So when your trying to create new building it trigger the error.

UPDATE:

```
class building(models.Model):
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True) --> you don't need this, the system automatically create id
    CUSTOMER = models.ForeignKey(customer, null=True, blank=True)
    BUILDING_USE = models.CharField(max_length=2, 
        blank=True, choices=c.Anvendelse, default="base on choices")
    BUILDING_FLOORSPACE  = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{0}' % (self)
```

Comment: ok thks @catherine. how do i do if it will also accept new building??

Comment: ID_Customer must be also null=True and blank=True. delete database and sync again

Comment: thks @catherine...done it and now i get another error ´Cannot assign "u''": "building.ID_CUSTOMER" must be a "customer" instance.´...what is that mean??

Comment: thank u so much..but may i ask is there any reason to put the ´default = "base on choices"´ also ´default=0´?. I did change as what u have updated and del db and syncdb then i get another error ´invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''´..so sorry for making this continually..

Comment: ´default = "base on choices" is based on your Anvendelse choice. Change the default value, don't copy that :). And about the ´default=0, it is valid for IntegerField if there is no value defined. That is the default value 0

Comment: you mean I have to write what are the choices for the Anvendelse choices? is that u mean the default??kinda a bit confuse:). i have actually written the choices in one file under format.py and i called it as c. thats why i have c.Anvendelse. is that make sense? thks @catherine

Comment: ok, can you just post your Anvendelse choices? I will just put the correct value in the default. Sorry if your bit confuse

Comment: ok..Anvendelse = [("01", 'Bolig'),("02", 'Andet'),]. thanks a lot @catherine...thats ok im a bit confuse as long as u are not confuse...:D...btw i still get this error..´Cannot assign "u''": "building.CUSTOMER" must be a "customer" instance.´. what should i look at when i get this error...thanks again:D

Comment: `default="02"` and about your problem, you need to create new customer then get the id. That id will serve as the value of CUSTOMER. Is that ok?

Comment: so i create the new customer from admin right??? oh no..when i login into my admin it gives me this error ´maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object´ mG what happen...:((

Comment: ok thks @catherine...i will try to fix it and will get back to this web when i'm stuck again....thank u so much for the help...have a nice day to u...:)